# vmware workstation version 8 impacts win7 host's internet performance

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am seeing strange behavior on 4 different people's desktop machines. All the machines are the same hardware and the problem is the same on all of the machines. When VMware Workstation 8 is running virtual machines, the hosting machine (Win7) has super slow web page retrievals.   If I suspend the VMs the problem goes away. Also, when the VMs are running, the VMs can pull web sites with no issue.   Both the hosting machine are pulling their networking information from the same DHCP server.

After reviewing the config, I have tried:

1. Ran wireshark to check for DNS lookup issues, but DNS comes back right away.   It is the TCP 80 connection that slows down.
2. Deleted the NAT and closed default networks from virtual networking in workstation.

Anyone seen something like this?

Comment: I have seen this exact behaviour with VMware Player with a WIN7 host and WIN2008R2 guest.  Tried a few tings I found in VMware forums but no help.  I created a new WIN2008R2 VM and issue went away.  Would like to know the cause and why new VM works differently

Comment: Did some more testing and found that if I remove VMware Bridging from the network config the issue goes away. Of course I lose the ability to have bridged VMs which is required.  Focusing my attention on the issues with that bridging component.

Comment: Tried updating the BIOS for the on-board nics and at VMware's recommendation I changed the bridging to manual from auto.   Still no change.